# SVN "Checkout" or "Diff against" first revision of each file

Tags: ubuntu, svn, version-control

I guess the title is already enough information, but anyway.

We have a SVN repository. It contains a huge number of files and folders.
Right now I have to find out what exactly changed during our development process within each file. If I compare the HEAD-revision with the first/oldest revision the svn-diff shows me "File X is only in HEAD". Therefore it has been added with some commit between the first and the HEAD-revision. 
Of course I could make a svn-diff between that revision and the HEAD revision, but then I would lose information about the changes made before that specific commit within other files.
So I would like to show the changes that were made within each file between the HEAD-revision and the revision were the file was commited. (If thats not possible directly, it is OK if there is a way to checkout the first revision of each file)

We use kdesvn on kubuntu if this piece of information is of any value.

Comment: If the file is only in HEAD, wouldn't your development process have created the ENTIRE file? Why do you need to know "since the point where I created this file I did these changes" instead of "since release X I did these changes"?